# Python take output from for loop and assign it elsewhere

Tags: python, loops, iteration

Re-posted with testable code as an example.

Hello all. Can you guys and gals please help me figure this out? I have been trying to take the output of a for loop and use it to print a summary page. I want each iteration from the for loop to be a column next to the last iteration. Can you please help achieve this? Your help is much appreciated.

import time, re, collections, operator

```
output_list = [['2016-07-12', 'Magazine', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo'],
['2016-07-12', 'Book', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo']]


def count_types():
    item_1 = mm_counts(1)
    item_2 = mm_counts(4)
    item_3 = mm_counts(3)

def mm_counts(a):
    r = []
    for i in output_list:
        x = (i[a])
        #x = (i[0] + ': ' + i[a])
        r.append(x)
    y = collections.Counter(r)
    #test_list = []
    for k, v in sorted(y.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        z = (str(k).ljust(5, ' ') + ' ' + (str(v).ljust(5, ' ')))
        print(z)   #<--- I want to print this column and iterate next columns next to each other.

count_types()
```

Current Output:

```
Magazine 1    
Book  1    
1234567 2    
Podcast 2
```

Desired Output:

```
Magazine 1  1234567 2
Book     1  Podcast 2
```

Comment: It looks like you are iterating over an empty `output_list` for a start. Can you post a reproducible example, perhaps with some sample data?

Comment: if i can run your code i will try to help.

have you thought about using something like pandas if you are looking for a grid?

Comment: Hi I re-posted with a testable example. Can you please review and see if you can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

Pick the number of columns you wants, print on one line with a tab after each element, and go to the next line each time you've printed the desired number of elements for each line.

If your goal is to have two columns, set desiredColumns to two. If your goal is two rows, set desiredColumns to the total number of things you'll be printing divided by two, and then rounded up.

```
import time, re, collections, operator

output_list = [
    ['2016-07-12', 'Magazine', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo'],
    ['2016-07-12', 'Book', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo']]


def count_types():
    item_1 = mm_counts(1)
    item_2 = mm_counts(4)
    item_2 = mm_counts(3)

def mm_counts(a):
    r = []
    for i in output_list:
        x = (i[a])
        #x = (i[0] + ': ' + i[a])
        r.append(x)
    y = collections.Counter(r)
    test_list = []

    wordsInColumn = 0
    desiredColumns = 2

    for k, v in sorted(y.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True):
        z = (str(k).ljust(5, ' ') + ' ' + (str(v).ljust(5, ' ')))
        print (z, end = '\t')
        wordsInColumn += 1
        if wordsInColumn % desiredColumns == 0:
          print('')

count_types()

#    output:
#    Magazine 1     Book  1     
#    1234567 2      Podcast 2
```

Comment: Hi, this works if the Key values do not change. If they do the formatting is off. Can I keep that formatting even if the keys change? For example if I had this as the input for the list: 'output_list = [['2016-07-12', 'Magazine', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo'],
['2016-07-12', 'Book', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo'],
['2016-07-12', 'Book', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo'],
['2016-07-12', 'Article', 'News Paper #2', 'Podcast', '1234567', '10-10-10-10', 'ABCDEFG', 'Zoo']] '

Comment: This should work, unless I'm not understanding what you'd like to do. Can you explain what you mean by 'summary page'? What exactly are you trying to print?